# I want to execute a procedure by passing input parameters of another procedure name

Tags: oracle, plsql, profiling

Here is the scenario.
I have N number of procedure,each with different input parameter and I want the execution time of each procedure to be stored in xyz table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TIME_CAPTURE IS

     before_procedure  timestamp;
     after_procedure timestamp;
     actual_time number;
     rpt_dt date;

BEGIN


select systimestamp into before_procedure from dual;
dbms_output.put_line (before_procedure );


proc_load('02/28/2013'); --- execution of procedure


select systimestamp into after_procedure from dual;
dbms_output.put_line (after_procedure);

select extract (second from (after_procedure-before_procedure)) into actual_time from dual;
dbms_output.put_line (actual_time);
END PROC_TIME_CAPTURE;
```

This is what i have done unitll now. But i want to make it dynamic. insteag of executing a procedure inside once. I want to pass the proc_name and date as input parameter to the main procedure and execute it.

I am new to this site so please ignore any errors or format issues while posting this query.

Please guide me whether this can be achieved or not.

Comment: have you tried dynamic sql , something on the lines of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: Why don't you use PL/SQL's built-in profiling capabilities instead?  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#sthref1068

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the procedure call you want as a string and then execute it using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TIME_CAPTURE( p_procedure_call VARCHAR2 )  IS

     before_procedure  timestamp;
     after_procedure timestamp;
     actual_time number;
     rpt_dt date;

BEGIN


select systimestamp into before_procedure from dual;
dbms_output.put_line (before_procedure );


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_procedure_call;


select systimestamp into after_procedure from dual;
dbms_output.put_line (after_procedure);

select extract (second from (after_procedure-before_procedure)) into actual_time from dual;
dbms_output.put_line (actual_time);
END PROC_TIME_CAPTURE;
```

You could pass the full procedure call including parameters. Etc...

```
BEGIN
  PROC_TIME_CAPTURE( 'proc_load( ''20/10/2010'' )' );
END;
```